# Session is not initializing if i run my nodejs server with ip address

Tags: mysql, node.js, express, session, passport.js

I am using nodejs with express 4 framework. I have setup my node project on server but the problem is that after the login it will not redirect me to dashboard page.
When i check "req.user" after login then it gave me undefined value although its working fine in my local system.

But when i point the ip with domain name then session is initializing successfully.  and it redirect me to dashboard page and also gave me req.user information.

This is my session code.

```
var sessionStore = new SessionStore({}, connection);
    // required for passport
    app.use(session({
            secret: '5372E653ED6BD22E09BF14DE621CAFBFEA8B1391C056B73F3A0FECB31BD4E1B8',
            cookie: { maxAge : 2592000000 },
            store: sessionStore,
            resave: true,
            saveUninitialized: true
        }));
    app.use(passport.initialize());
    app.use(passport.session()); // persistent login sessions
    app.use(flash()); // use connect-flash for flash messages stored in session
    app.use(routes);
```

Route code (after login)

```
 router.all('/user/*', function (req, res, next) {
    if (!req.user) {
      res.redirect("/login.html");
  } else { 
      next();
  }
});
```

Any Idea?

Answer (score 0):

I think it is *intentionally* happening in the browser.  This doesn't sound like an express issue.

Related issues here:

[IP and domain create different session](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11836914/ip-and-domain-create-different-session)

[Why does the session cookie work when serving from a domain but not when using an IP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27254013/why-does-the-session-cookie-work-when-serving-from-a-domain-but-not-when-using-a)